# Ensure std::bind provides the right number of arguments

Tags: c++

After changing the signature of a `std::function`, I was wondering that the compiler did not complain about the function signatures I did not change yet.

Basically, my code looks like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class CallbackCaller
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (unsigned, int)> CallbackFunction;

    void registerCallbackFunction(CallbackFunction cb_function)
    {
        callback_functions_.push_back(cb_function);
    }

    void callThemAll()
    {
        for (CallbackFunction &cb_function : callback_functions_)
            cb_function(5, -3);
    }

private:
    std::vector<CallbackFunction> callback_functions_;
};

class CallbackHandler
{
public:
    CallbackHandler(CallbackCaller &callback_caller)
    {
        callback_caller.registerCallbackFunction(std::bind(&CallbackHandler::f1, this, std::placeholders::_1)); // !!!
        callback_caller.registerCallbackFunction(std::bind(&CallbackHandler::f2, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

private:
    void f1(unsigned x)
    {
        std::cout << "f1: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void f2(unsigned x, int y)
    {
        std::cout << "f2: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CallbackCaller callback_caller;
    CallbackHandler callback_handler(callback_caller);
    callback_caller.callThemAll();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `registerCallbackFunction` accept `f1` even though its signature mismatches? Is there a way to make the compilation of this code fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::bind` has no foreknowledge about the fact it's going to be stored in a `std::function` that expects a specific thing. It only knows about the signature of the member function it's being given. So it will require you bind `this` and *one placeholder*.

After that it merely provides a function object with a templated variadic function call operator. Said function call operator has the property of accepting any number of arguments, and **not using any excess arguments**. It won't complain, it will simply evaluate and then proceed to ignore what it doesn't need. And again, it only needs one argument.

`std::function` in turn checks that the functor it's being given can be called with 2 arguments. And a templated function call operator can do just that. It accepts the second argument, and discards it. All perfectly legal.

The superior alternative to `std::bind` would be a generic lambda:

```
//callback_caller.registerCallbackFunction([this](auto&& ...x) {f1(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);}); // !!!
callback_caller.registerCallbackFunction([this](auto&& ...x) {f2(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)...);});
```

Now there is far less type erasure going on, and the number of argument given to the lambda must match the number of arguments `f1` and `f2` expect, or there will be an error.

Since C++14, the use cases for `std::bind` are virtually non-existent.